# HTML Select box - getting rid of arrow and its space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get rid of the arrow of a select box and all its traces as is the space for that arrow for example.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kud7Z/

I hid arrow using this CSS:

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

However there's still a space on the right of the select box. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select boxes are notoriously hard to style.

I've found this technique to be nice, easy, and work well cross-browser: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Essentially, you turn the select transparent, and place it in a slightly smaller, overflow hidden wrapper `<div>` with your field styling. This lops off the right-hand side of the select box and leaves just your visual stylings.

Comment: This seems to be the only way... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `-moz-appearance: listbox;` instead of `none`. Rely on `box-shadow` and not `border` to draw borders, as `border` will cause the dropdown button to appar.

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: listbox;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray;    
}
```

This is how it looks in Firefox 25 (Mac):

[image]

Also, you may find the following page useful, you can try differnt valuse for -moz-appearance depending on what you're trying to achieve.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Comment: This even shows the arrow again which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/XBUwD/

Comment: what version of Firefox are you using? going to update the answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Ah! I see, my bad. You might find some other value that works for `-moz-appearance` in the mozilla dev link I shared above.